# Suppressing whitespace at end of environment

Tags: spacing, environments

This must have been answered before, but I'm afraid I can't find it.  I'm defining an environment and I want the end block to be formatted immediately after the end of the contents, without intervening horizontal space.  Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{example}{[\textit{Example} --- }{]}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
This is an example.
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Obviously I can achieve this by putting a `%` on the end of the contents line, e.g.

```
\begin{example}
This is an example.%
\end{example}
```

... but that's not practical as I only have control of the environment definition, not the use of it.  Is there anything I can add to the definition of the environment to kill the horizontal space that otherwise gets inserted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `\unskip` before the `]` in the closing part of the environment definition.  This will eat up any space characters prior to the `]`.

EDIT to heed Barbara's comment to remove stray space following em-dash.  And as she notes, one cannot have a blank line before `\end{example}` without automatically introducing a paragraph break.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{example}{[\textit{Example} ---}{\unskip]}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
This is an example.
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Furthermore, if you wish not to have the blank space *after* the closing `]`, you need `\ignorespacesafterend`, as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{example}{[\textit{Example} ---}{\unskip]\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
This is an example.
\end{example}
xxx
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: two comments: the space following the dash is wider than the space before it, so add `\ignorespaces` at the end of the first argument.  second, there can't be a blank line before `\end{example}`; if input it's most likely unintended, so this is just a warning.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you really want an environment for this. However, you can (ab)use `environ`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{example}{%
  [\textit{Example} --- \BODY]%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
This is an example.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]